# Print a field when certain value is not present Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a *JasperReports*'s report using iReport. I have a date field where once instance is `01-JAN-1900`. I need any time the date field has this value then `null` value is printed. I have tried this:

```
<textField pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="4dd05795-8363-4cf3-ad30-239aac3a086f" x="3" y="0" width="63" height="15">
                        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRAN_DATE} != "01-JAN-1900"]]></printWhenExpression>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="9"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TRAN_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
```

But the value is still getting printed. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can change the getter in your Java class that provides the value: 

return value.equals("01-JAN-1900") ? null : value;

Comment: It is coming from an sql select statement and I cannot make it null before getting it in the report as the report is ordered by date.

Comment: What is type of $F{TRAN_DATE} ? If this is java.util.Date comparision with String will not work. Maybe you should try comparing intValue with 0 ($F{TRAN_DATE}.intValue() != 0 ? ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare dissimilar types. Drop the String literal and compare datetime types.

Comment: if $F{TRAN_DATE} is of type java.util.Date then use equals() to test for equality and after() or before () to test for precedence.

Answer (score 0):

If your field $F{TRAN_DATE} is in java.util.Date type, change it to java.lang.String and your condition should work.